# Enable/Disable MIDI channel in android (java)

Tags: java, android, midi

I am developing a simple application in android that does MIDI playback and thats fine.
I was wondering if it is possible to enable/disable MIDI channels with the android/java built-in API, and if so how? I am struggling to implement this feature.

I found out on the internet that the java package "javax.sound(.midi)" was included in earlier version of the android system but was later removed. I can't seem to find any library on the internet that provides the functionality that I need. 
One library I came across allowed me to add and remove tracks from MIDI, but a track is different from channel.

I have a MediaPlayer object with midi file set as the data source and it does play the file, but I really want to implement a feature to enable/disable any of the 16 standard midi channels. It doesn't need to be in real-time, any solution is acceptable as long as it does not require server-side. Like if I need to modify the existing midi file, write it to disk and  restart the playback its not a problem. Any suggestions/experience :\ !?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library can do what you're asking: https://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Read the file. Iterate over events in each track, check the channel of the event, remove the ones on the specified channel. Write it out. Play it. Rejoice.

Comment: Thank you very much, by the moment I've received and read this reply I already had done it myself using the same library that you mentioned. It is not very efficient though, there is some delay in the iteration and writing the file which ruins the experience for real time playing

Comment: @SpeedDemon I used the library you referenced and played the midi files using MediaPlayer.  I had no success with any of the midi channels (besides the piano).  Did you use MediaPlayer?  If not what did you use?  If so, what trick did you use to enable the other channels?

Comment: @stephen In the library you have a function that removes notes from the midi. You can iterate the collection of notes in the midi and check what channel the note is on and remove it if it is on a channel you want to disable. You need to write the midi to disk and then play it with MediaPlayer. I can email you the code snippet later that worked for me

Comment: @SpeedDemon Thanks for the response.  I realized that I had assumed the MIDI channels were mapped to the various MIDI sounds.  When in fact you can choose to assign a sound to each channel via a program change.  But they are not assigned by default.